# Dynamic unpacking in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Python lacks dynamic unpacking. Example: You want to unpack a list, let's say coordinates, but don't know whether it contains 3 items or just 2.

`x, y, z = [1,2,3]` works only if `len([x,y,z]) == len([1,2,3])`.

`x, y, z = [1,2]` results in an error. You could add `try` and `except` blocks but that could be complicated.

The best option is `z` being `None`, as you can simply check using `if n is None` without any excessive `try`/`except`.

So expected result:

```
>>> x, y, z = unpack([1,2])
>>> print(x)
1
>>> print(y)
2
>>> print(z)
None
```

### My code

```
def unpack(num, list):
    return_arr = [None] * num
    for i,elem in enumerate(list):
        return_arr[i] = elem
        if i+1 == num:
            return return_arr
    return return_arr
```

And usage examples:

```
a,b,c,d = unpack(4, [1,2,3])
print(a),
print(b),
print(c),
print(d),
print("\n")

e,f,g = unpack(3, [1,2,3])
print(e),
print(f),
print(g)
```

resulting in

```
1 2 3 None 

1 2 3
```

You basically have to specify the amount of variables you're unpacking the list to, since the function can't know that.

Comment: I'm wondering if it would be possible to create a class for iterables that will unpack dynamically (by magically having the right length or something).  I've been trying to answer this, but I couldn't.

Comment: @OskarSkog Just replace the `__iter__` method of your class by this `unpack` (granted you make it return an iterator).

Comment: @OskarSkog Nevermind, not really as you can't pass the number of variable you want to unpack into to the `__iter__` method, but I would start digging in that direction anyway.

Comment: I just started thinking about it and realised that an infinite iterable would be easy to make but that would have too many value to unpack. I guess "Python lacks dynamic unpacking." really means what it means.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. It is generaly a bad idea to shadow a builtin (like `list`) by using a variable named after it.
2. You can use slices and array extension to simplify a bit your algorithm:

   ```
   def unpack(n, lst):
       result = lst[:n]
       return result + [None] * (n - len(result))
   ```
3. You can use the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module to improve memory management and allow for any iterable:

   ```
   import itertools


   def unpack(n, iterable):
       infinite = itertools.chain(iterable, itertools.repeat(None))
       return itertools.islice(infinite, n)
   ```
4. Python 3 has an extended unpacking capability that is closer to your needs:

   ```
   >>> x, y, *z = [1, 2]
   >>> print(x, y, z)
   1, 2, []
   ```

Comment: Awesome point, didn't realize I can just return a slice and each part of *the rest* as `None`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

1. The function has no docstring. What does it do? How do I call it? Are there any helpful examples you can present? The text in the post would make a good start.
2. The name `unpack` is poorly chosen. I know that sequence unpacking is the use case that you have in mind, but the function does not actually unpack anything. What it does is to return a fixed-length prefix of a sequence, padding with `None` if necessary to make it up to the required length. So a name like `prefix_pad_none` would give a clearer indication of the behaviour. (Compare with the [`padnone` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in the `itertools` documentation.)
3. The pad value `None` should be a parameter to the function (with default value of `None`). That's because there are use cases in which you might want to pad a sequence with some other value. For example, zero, one, and NaN are common pad values in mathematical code.

Revised code:

```
from itertools import chain, islice, repeat

def prefix_pad(n, iterable, padvalue=None):
    """Return the first n elements of iterable, padded out with padvalue
    if iterable has fewer than n elements.

    """
    return islice(chain(iterable, repeat(padvalue)), n)
```

Comment: Good point about the name